# Software Center Messing Around (Ubuntu 21.04)

Tags: apt, gnome, system-installation, software-installation, software-center

Prior to this I disabled settings in the Software & Updates such as Community Maintained software. After a while the Software Center disappeared. I restarted  the computer and it was still gone. I installed the gnome-software center from terminal but it isn't quite like the original one and installed additional applications such as Packages.

How to install the original one without reinstalling the OS?

I'm running Ubuntu 21.04. I'm also concerned that this software center is not going to get things like updates. It's also using an old icon as opposed to the newer and original one Ubuntu provides.

Answer (score 6):

"the original one" (which is a fork of `gnome-software`) is delivered as snap package, so to install it again you'd have to `sudo snap install snap-store`.

To remove `gnome-software` you'd have to: `sudo apt remove gnome-software`. If you'd also want to uninstall no longer needed dependencies (e.g. those that got pulled in while installing gnome-software) run: `sudo apt autoremove`.